# Not seeing service contract when I add WCF service as a service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am looking at a WCF service created by one of our team-members and trying to add it as a service reference in my client code. My knowledge of WCF is not extremely deep but normally after adding service reference, I should be able to see the list of functions in the Object Browser if I extend the service.

Now,normally a service contract looks like following:

```
 [OperationContract]
  void Functionname(Parameter request);
```

However, this one looks a little different and I am not sure if it not showing up in the list of the functions has anything to do with it being different but it looks like following:

```
[OperationContractAttribute(Action = "SomeName", ReplyAction = "*")]
        [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
        ResponseType SomeName(ParameterNamerequest);
```

So here goes my final question:

- How can I add this service in my client code and still be able to call this functions? Since it is not showing in "Callable" function list, do I have to change this service to be able to call it?
- what is the real use/ benefit of doing it this way?

Comment: Dont use generated service reference. Instead define all the service contracts and data contracts in one assembly, and share this assembly between the service implementation and the client, then on the client you can use ChannelFactory to call the service...very simple, very readable (than the generated one) .

Comment: Because ReplyAction="*" you can't get the schema when you try to add a web reference. As Dan said, you can put the contract interface in an assembly and share the reference with your client, or you can remove the ReplayAction, or you can also export the wsdl schema to a file using the WcfSvcHost.exe utility and use with your client application to create the classes.